# Eclipse and copying workspaces

Tags: eclipse

What do I have to do to copy a complete workspace from one computer to another and be simply able to continue working on it on the other computer?

Comment: A tip: In the long run you will benefit greatly from being able to get a virgin Eclipse installation up and running with the appropriate code.  This means source code repository checkouts etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general, a filesystem copy should be sufficient.  If you run into problems with your projects, try removing the project from the workspace (without deleting the files) and then re-add the project, which will rebuild the metadata.

Comment: Removing and adding the projects seems best (since the workspace contains absolute paths I believe?)

Comment: The workspace mostly uses relative paths.  I've been successfully keeping a workspace on a flash drive, even when the flash drive gets assigned different drive letters on different computers.  I'm assuming these are JDT projects we're talking about?

Comment: What if I want to preserve my `.metadata` folder, where I have so many syntax coloring settings which are so hard to set again?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you shut down eclipse before you copy the workspace, and that the target computer has the same (or higher) eclipse version, including the same plugins.

Check that your workspace actually contains all the projects - when creating a project, it's possible to have its files situated outside the workspace.

If your projects use any external libraries installed on the system, install these on the other system in the same place (or adjust the paths).

Then, there should be no problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In addition, though, make sure you have the same plugins installed on the target computer (if you are using any additional plugins)

Comment: Another addition: copying the workspace will only work if you have no external resources (imported into the workspace but not copied during import), or these are in the same location on the source and target systems.

Comment: Also, check your Target Platform Preferences, the default setup should be fine, but if you've edited the target, then you may need to adjust paths.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have any issues with a straight filesystem copy as long as your eclipse versions match up.

If they don't, the project metadata may not load correctly

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the whole folder which you select as your workspace at startup (or you once selected). All settings are included in there (even the opened files).

Answer (score 2):

I use [rsync](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/) for this.  Works great.