# Eclipse C/C++ (CDT) switching workspaces (sharing)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to share a workspace in Eclipse.  To test it I copied my current workspace to a different directory.  Then when eclipse loads it pops up a dialog box to select a workspace.
When I changed the workspace to the one I copied it did not work.  It did not load the workspace I copied and loaded the default screen.  Is there anyway to save a workspace to a different location and reload it for later use?

I am using eclipse 3.7.0 on ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493997/eclipse-and-copying-workspaces.

Comment: I think I have to use import.  I used import and got it to build but now I can't get it to run.  It thinks its a java project when it is a C/C++ project.

Comment: I tried importing an exported project settings and that dialog does not work. Seems like a bug. Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by exporting a project archive. Then importing the project as an archive in a new workspace.