# How to seperate Eclipse workspace as android and normal Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

in eclipse ı have android apps and java web apps together in my workspace  . I want to seperate them 2 different workspace so ı created new Folder workspaceAndroid and copied android apps into this folder manually but all projects contains path or jar errors now . So , how can ı seperate them in correct way ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse and copying workspaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493997/eclipse-and-copying-workspaces)

Answer (score 3):

First you need to Export android projects into a archive. For that choose *File* -> *Export* -> *General - Archive File*. Then select all Android projects you want to move, give a name of archive file and press finish.

Then you need to switch workspace using *File* -> *Switch Workspace* -> *Other*. Choose new workspace directory and press ok.

Now you can import your projects using *File* - *Import* - *General* - *Existing Projects into Workspace* -> choose *Select Archive File* option, choose your zip file and press finish.

The projects must be there.

To delete projects from workspace you need to switch back to the old workspace. Then select projects, do right mouse click and choose *Delete*. Don't forget to set a check on *Delete project content on disk* checkbox. Otherwise projects' content will stay in the workspace folder.

Comment: So, , how can ı delete archived apps from old workspace at the same time ?

Comment: To delete projects from workspace you need to switch back to the old workspace. Then select projects, do right mouse click and choose *Delete*. Don't forget to set a check on *Delete project content on disk* checkbox. Otherwise projects' content will stay in the workspace folder.

Comment: I imported android archive into adt eclipse. now there is no src folder in any app and any project cannot run . Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Make sure you selected everything (all files and folders of a project) during the export.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it manually, create a new workspace for java projects and then select and import java only projects and check on of copy them into workspace using eclipse only. Workspace has .metadata folder that might be creating problem for u. doing this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is so called "Working sets". Press the little downwards pointing arrow in the package explorer, and press "Select Working Set...". Press "New..." and select your type of the working set, and simply add the project you want to belong to that set!

When you are done with that, you can press the same arrow as beror, and press "Select Working Set" to choose when you want to use the android- or java-projects.